# Android Project with ActionBarSherlock doesn't get built

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I implemented the current version of ActionBarSherlock to my Android Project.
Everything works fine and I don't get any errors.

But when I try to debug or export my project I don't get an .apk-file out of my project. Just a .jar-file with the name of my project.

I've read about some problems the SDK had with building projects that contain external libraries but this was at SDK version 14 and so I hope, this bug is fixed...

So there might be another cause for this problem.

Does anybody know a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get *.jar file as the result of building Android project. This seems very strange to me. There must be something wrong with your project settings (if you changed them), or the project you build is of the wrong type (i.e. it is *Java Application* instead of *Android Application*).

You didn't mention which IDE do you use, but I assume you use Eclipse.
Make sure you have installed **Android SDK** and **Eclipse ADT** correctly (just in case).
Next thing to try is to create a new Android Application project from existing sources (there should be such option during the process of creation).

Comment: Seems to be a fault in my project settings. I accidently have checked "is library" in my library-settings. Now I get an .apk

Thank you.